# Why the TableName is "Table" in SQL while getting the row by Unique Id?

Tags: c#, sql, datatable, dataset

I have a method to get DataSet by Id for address book application.

```
    public DataSet GetElementById(int id)
    {
        string commtext = string.Format("select * from ADDRESSES where Id={0}", id);
        DataSet set = new DataSet();
        adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(commtext, connection);
        adapter.Fill(set);
        return set;
    }
```

I have only one table in Access named `ADDRESSES` but `set.Tables[0].TableName` returns as `Table` despite I have no table such that. Why is this happening?

Comment: The name of the table largely irrelevant to the data it holds.  That is a very wasteful means to query one row

Comment: I want to update ListView when a datarow has been changed. So I need to  query that row again to get the updated data. Is this a wrong way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `OleDbDataAdapter` doesn't try to parse your query to extract the table name or try to read the name from the database.

It will be a performance hit for no meaningful reasons. It defaults to name each table retrieved to a sequential namig starting from "Table" then "Table1" and so on. You can see this [explained on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y4b211hz(v=vs.110).aspx)

> ... Additional result sets are named by
>   appending integral values to the specified table name (for example,
>   "Table", "Table1", "Table2", and so on).

Besides if you really need to assign a value to the first table you can simply pass the name for the table using the overload that takes an additional string parameter

```
adapter.Fill(set, "ADDRESSES");
```